# Context menu related problem

Tags: c#, winforms

suppose my context menu is associated with 3  label control. when i will right click on those label then context menu will appear. i want to capture from the context menu click event that on which label the context menu click event called. i tried but failed.

```
 void MyContextMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            if (((Label)sender).Name.ToUpper() == "LBLACCOUNTREFERENCE")
            {
                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.OemText, (object)((Label)sender).Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.OemText, (object)this.localJob.JobPart.OEReference);
        }
    }
```

please guide me.

Comment: In the future, please add tags for the platform (`winforms`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` parameter specifies the menu item that was clicked.
You're looking for the [`SourceControl` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx), which gives you the control that opened the `ContextMenuStrip`.

Check `contextMenu.SourceControl.Text`.

Comment: i am working with ContextMenu not ContextMenuStrip. if i use the same ContextMenu for many control then how do i decide that user right click on which control from the ContextMenu click event. i know it is easy to detect from ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl but i am not working with ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: You should.  `ContextMenuStrip` is much nicer.  However, `ContextMenu` has the same property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol.aspx